# How can I reference a string variable in a map:util element in a spring xml file when the string is defined in the same file?

Tags: java, spring, variables, selenium, xpath

Below is the context of an xml file where I am defining a map and its elements. Some of the elements in the map will end up being comprised of xpaths where some portion of the xpaths will be the same. I want to create variables that will represent the portions of those xpaths that are redundant across elements.

I have defined a bean with an id and a property and a value. No matter what I try, I am unable to reference the value of the bean. All I ever get when I ask for the value of Map.get("devo").get("error404CategoriesContainer") is "${errorContainer}". I want it to give me "//div[@id='noResultsFeatures']//div[contains(@class,'noResultsFeaturesContainer')]".

The bean I am trying to create as a variable starts at <bean id="errorContainer"
The map entry where I am trying to use it is the <entry key="error404CategoriesContainer" element. Regardless of which 3 things I try, I always get the same value. The text value of the item in the map, not the text value of the variable.

I have searched everywhere, but I am not able to find a solution. I have tried a # symbol instead of a $ symbol. I have tried different ways of defining the bean and trying to "ref" the bean, all to no avail. Can someone guide me to a solution?

Here is the content of the xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.0.xsd">

<bean id="errorContainer" class="java.lang.String">
    <property name="error404CategoryContainer" value="//div[@id='noResultsFeatures']//div[contains(@class,'noResultsFeaturesContainer')]"/>
</bean>

<util:map id="devo">
    <entry key="FourOFour">
        <util:map>                
            <entry key="error404FeaturedCategoriesHeader" value="//h2[@id='noResultsFeaturesHeader' and contains(text(),'Featured Categories')]" />


   None of these works – I only have one in the file at a time.

            <entry key="error404CategoriesContainer" value="${errorContainer}" />
            <entry key="error404CategoriesContainer" value="${errorContainer. error404CategoryContainer}" />
            <entry key="error404CategoriesContainer" value="${error404CategoryContainer}" />


            <entry key="error404CategoriesContainerLinks" value="//div[@id='noResultsFeatures']//div[contains(@class,'noResultsFeaturesContainer')][${1}]//ul//li" />
            <entry key="error404CategoriesContainerLinkByCategoryAndLinkNumber" value="//div[@id='noResultsFeatures']//div[contains(@class,'noResultsFeaturesContainer')][${1}]//ul//li[${2}]//a" />
        </util:map>
    </entry>
</util:map>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer to your application context with <context:property-placeholder ... />. In the, you can define properties as key-value pairs and refer to the values with ${key} syntax.

See here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.html